# Pasar información de servidor node con express a servicio Angular

Tags: html, nodejs, angular, express

Desde Angular en mi componente HTML, yo invoco a una app ajena y me redirije a esa app y la invoco de la siguiente manera.

```
<body>
   <form [action]="urlDeAppAjena" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="parametrosRequest" [value]="parametrosRequest"></input> 
         <button type="submit">Ir a app ajena</button>
   </form>
</body>
```

Una vez que hago el submit me redijire a la app agena, esto estando en la misma pestaña, hago mu flujo que tengo que hacer en mi app ajena.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al finalizar el flujo en la app ajena, ellos me invocan a mi API node de una manera similar a como yo lo invoqué y es por POST

```
<body>
   <form action="localhost/api/users" method="POST" id="prueba">
         <input type="hidden" name="parametrosResponse" value="parametros en un Json"></input> 
         <button type="submit">Devolver info</button>
   </form>
</body>
```

Y en node + express tengo esto
[server.js]

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express(),
bodyParser = require("body-parser");
port = 3080;

const users = [];

let parametros = "";

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {
    parametros = req.body.parametrosResponse;
    res.json("Se reciben los parámetros exitosamente " + parametros);
});
```

hasta este punto todo bien, porque recibo los parámetros y los puedo manipular y todo, y en mi pestaña del navegador se ve esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero ahora en este mismo punto, en esta misma pestaña, necesito que me redirija a un componente de Angular, por ejemplo a: **localhost/miAppAngular/procesaUsers** y desde el service de de ese componentes ejemplo: *users.service.ts* pueda hacer uso de esos parámetros que me enviaron por POST y que ya tengo almacenados en el server.js.

Todos los ejemplos que he visto, simplemente desde Angular llaman al API y esperan una respuesta, pero en este caso yo estoy dentro del contexto del API post y necesito salir de ahí e ir a un componente de Angular y llevarme esos parámetros al service de Angular.

Me basé de acá https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-develop-and-build-angular-app-with-nodejs-e24c40444421
Pero ahí todo se maneja en la misma página y no redirecciona como lo hace mi app

Nota: Nada puede ser por GET, ya que para eso hice el API, para recibir los parámetros por post y tiene que ser en la misma pestaña, algo muy similar a como es un proceso con Paypal y la app externa tiene seguridad y no puede ser embebida en un html, si quisiera ponerla en un model o algo así, no tendría acceso, por eso estoy obligado a realizar esos redirect.

Comment: Hola que tal. En mi opinión las redirecciones que planteas no son necesarias. Todo puede suceder dentro de angular. El objetivo de las API generalmente es dar una estructura de comunicación entre aplicaciones. Así que puedes hacer todas tus operaciones desde el formulario de angular y esperar respuesta para, ahora si, desde angular, redirigir al otro formulario. Se sale también del principio de angular de hacer todo en una sola página. (Que cambia de componentes). Aun con lo que te he dicho, crees necesarias las redirecciones?

Comment: Edito la pregunta. la app externa no puede ser embebida en algún html porque tiene seguridad, entonces solo se puede acceder si es un redirect completo, por eso no puedo meter la app externa en un model o algo así, y por eso estoy obligado a hacer todos esos redireccionamientos.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu controlador solo necesitas agregar esta linea:

`res.redirect('https://tu-app.co')`

Quedando de esta manera:

```
app.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {
    parametros = req.body.parametrosResponse;
    res.redirect('https://tu-app.co')
});
```

Con esto supongo que el usuario está viendo ese controlador de la manera que lo muestras en tus ejemplos.

Mira mas [aqui](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) sobre `redirect`.

## Edicicion

Si lo que estás haciendo solo es un redireccionamiento de los parametros ya recibidos intenta agregando el estatus `307`

> ## [307 Temporary Redirect (desde HTTP/1.1)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP#3xx:_Redirecciones)
>
> Se trata de una redirección que debería haber sido hecha con otra URI, sin embargo aún puede ser procesada con la URI proporcionada. En contraste con el código 303, el método de la petición no debería ser cambiado cuando el cliente repita la solicitud. Por ejemplo, una solicitud POST tiene que ser repetida utilizando otra petición POST

Modifica tu código de esta manera:

```
res.redirect('https://tu-app.co')
```

Mas [informacion aqui](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/redirect)

Comment: Gracias, el redirect funciona bien, pero ahora necesito pasar los parámetros, y recibirlos en mi service de angular sin que los parámetros viajen en la URL, ¿hay alguna manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Que tantos datos son?

Comment: En este punto ya podría mandar todo en un JSON

Comment: Edito la pregunta.

Comment: Veo que ese redirect lo que hace es reenviar la petición post pero el tema es que Angular no puede recibir peticiones POST, el objetivo de mi api es recibir esas peticiones POST que Angular no puede recibir, pero el problema con el que me encuentro en estos momentos es que no puedo pasar esos parámetros que recibí por post en mi API a un service de Angular. necesito que al hacer redirect a localhost/miAppAngular/procesaUsers el service de ese componente pueda hacer uso de la información que tiene la variable parametros que se encuentra en el API

Comment: En ese caso guarda los datos en una session temporalmente. Y pasa un valor único como referencia por la url, con angular mandas eso de nuevo a tu API y obtienes los datos en tu sesión.

Comment: Puedes ver esto: https://devcode.la/tutoriales/como-configurar-sesiones-en-expressjs/

Comment: Esa es una muy buena opción, también las cookies, pero seguiré en busca de alternativas, muchas gracias por el apoyo.